# What I am not sure is whether the mean will run against a concatenation of the all the columns with said name across some N number of csv files

Tags: r, file, dataframe, mean

I have a directory with hundred of .csv files in it.
I grab the names of the files in the directory and save to "matrix"

```
files_names
#  [1] "001.csv" "002.csv" "003.csv" "004.csv" "005.csv" "006.csv" "007.csv" "008.csv" "009.csv" "010.csv"
# [11] "011.csv" "012.csv" "013.csv" "014.csv" "015.csv" "016.csv" "017.csv" "018.csv" "019.csv" "020.csv"
...
#[331] "331.csv" "332.csv"


files_names[1:2],
#[1] "001.csv" "002.csv"
```

Next, I read a subset, of the file names into data frame

```
class(dataframe)
#[1] "matrix"
attributes(dataframe)
#$dimnames[[1]]
#[1] "Date" "sulfate" "nitrate" "ID"     
#$dimnames[[2]]
#[1] "001.csv" "002.csv"

column_name = "sulfate"
```

What I am not sure is whether the mean will run against a concatenation of the all the columns with said name across some N number of csv files.

```
out <- mean(dataframe[[column_name]], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: What language are you using? Please tag the question with it.

Comment: Using 'R'
I have a directory with hundred of .csv files in it.
I grab the names of the files in the directory and save to "matrix"